# Using GlibC, what is the analog of _snscanf() from Windows?

Tags: c, linux, curl, libcurl, glibc

I have started going through the samples of the cURL, in C. While compiling `ftpuploadresume.c` I am getting undefined reference error at:

```
/* _snscanf() is Win32 specific */
r = _snscanf(ptr, size * nmemb, "Content-Length: %ld\n", &len);
```

I just want to know what is the alternative to `_snscanf` for glibc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you use null terminated strings, you can perfectly safely use `sscanf()` without the second (length) argument.  You could on Windows, too.  If you don't know that the string is null terminated but you do know how long it is, add the null terminator.  (If you don't know how long the string is and don't know whether it is null terminated, *nothing* is safe!)

Assuming you have a C99 compiler, you can work the necessary change automatically:

```
#define _snscanf(data, length, format, ...) scanf(data, format, __VA_ARGS__)
```

---

### Beware!

Note the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407590/using-glibc-what-is-the-analog-of-snscanf-from-windows/9407652?noredirect=1#comment44735272_9407652) by [namey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/434500/namey) — for which, thanks.

Look at the Microsoft man pages on [`_snscanf()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wez13747.aspx).  The examples are not compelling; you'd get the same results even without the length being specified.  However, it does look as though @namey is correct in general. A lot is going to depend on the context in which it is used. If the `length` specified is actually `strlen(data)`, then the difference isn't going to matter. If the length specified is longer than that, the difference probably isn't going to matter. If the length is smaller than the length of the data, the difference might matter quite a lot.

A better cover function might be:

```
int _snscanf(const char *input, size_t length, const char *format, ...)
{
    char *copy = malloc(length + 1);
    if (copy == 0)
        return 0;
    memmove(copy, input, length);
    copy[length] = '\0';
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    int rc = vsscanf(copy, format, args);
    va_end(args);
    free(copy);
    return rc;
}
```

Comment: It will read the entire string.  Why do you need to limit it?  Is the input not NUL-terminated?  You could add a terminator.

Comment: Adding the terminator is what I always do. If I have a buffer that must be terminated, I write the '\0' to the last byte before using it. Easy and guarantees termination.

Comment: because the curl library is handling this, not I. And the example is written for win32 compatibility only :)

Comment: Sadly, scanf cannot be used on parts of strings (without copying them) while _snscanf can be.

Comment: @namey: Thanks! Microsoft on [`_snscanf()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wez13747.aspx). The examples are not compelling; you'd get the same results even without the length being specified. However, it does look as though you're correct in general. A lot is going to depend on the context in which it is used. If the `size` specified is actually `strlen(data)`, then the difference isn't going to matter. If the size specified is longer than that, the difference probably isn't going to matter. If the size is smaller than the length of the data, the difference might matter quite a lot.

Comment: Please update your post, "vfscanf" should be "vsscanf". (btw, thanks :- )

Comment: PS: memcpy is *faster* (or equal) than memmove because it doesn't need to account for possible array overlap.

Comment: @LucBloom: AFAIAC, `memmove()` is always correct so I always use it. If you wish to use `memcpy()`, you may.

Answer (score 0):

If you are *sure* that the string passed to `_snscanf` is a valid null-terminated string, you could simply use [sscanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sscanf.3.html) with `%n` e.g.

```
 int pos = -1;
 int limit = size * nmemb;
 r = sscanf(ptr, "Content-Length: %ld\n%n", &len, &pos);
 if (r>0  &&  pos >= limit) {
    r = 0;  
    len = -1;
 }
```

The `%n` conversion specification sets the pointed integer to the current scanning offset. So we use `sscanf`, it may scan past the limit, but in that case we reject the scan (by setting `r = 0`). Of course, we have to accept that `len` could have been set.

BTW, my solution is not [GNU glibc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) specific, it should work with other POSIX compliant libc-s like [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/)